# Include CoffeeScript classes like in node.js

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, require

I am just getting use to CoffeeScript and I have gotten stuck with classes.
I want to have my files structured like in node so that I can require a JavaScript file containing a class like this.

`Test = require "test.js"`

`Test.start()`

Where start is a method of the Test Class.

Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "*like in node*", do you try to execute your coffeescript in the browser or in Node.js?

Comment: I am executing it in the browser but the require function doesn't work.

Comment: Of course not, there is no `require` in browser environments.

Comment: Is there any way a achieving something similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this possible?

Not exactly like in Node. There is no synchronous `require` in browser environments. Yet, you could try one of the many asynchronous libraries to do that, have a look at [AMD](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD). The most famous implementation is [require.js](http://requirejs.org/).

Comment: `No. There is no synchronous require in browser environments` -- wrong. But you should bundle all your code together for syncronous require to be feasible. Stitch, hem and browserify use that approach.

Comment: @nl_0: Sure, browserify and co can take synchronous-requiring code and transform it into an async one, but you can hardly load files synchronously from the browser.

Comment: @Bergi, yes, that's right, but the OP didn't ask anything about sync vs async. It seems to me that they just wanted to know if they could use Node.js-style modules in the browser. So the answer to "Is this possible?" -> "No" doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: @epidemian: That's right, I've removed the *No* now. I had equated "node.js-style" with "synchronous" :-/

Comment: @Bergi
"browserify and co can take synchronous-requiring code and transform it into an async one" -- no, it is not transformed into async, instead, the bundle is loaded asynchronously, and all the `require`s work synchronously after that.
"you can hardly load files synchronously from the browser" -- correct.

Answer (score 3):

I've found that the simplest way to use CommonJS modules (the ones that Node.js uses) in browser environments is to use [Browserify](http://browserify.org/). I personally also prefer the CommonJS module definitions to the the AMD ones, but that's just personal taste.

Also, take into account that in order to export your classes so that `require 'test'` will give you the class constructor directly, you would have to assign your class to `module.exports`:

```
# In test.coffee
module.exports = class Test 
  @start = -> console.log 'start!'
```

Then compile that file to `test.js` and you're ready to use it:

```
Test = require './test'
Test.start()
```

In Node.js this will Just Work. In browsers, you will need to process the files first with Browserify (or some other tool) to get it working (it will create the proper `require` function as well as some `exports` and `module.exports` variables for CommonJS modules to work correctly).

Comment: You are confusing RequireJS and CommonJS. Node uses CommonJS, while RequireJS is the most popular AMD implementation.

Comment: Yep, totally messed that up. I was thinking of CommonJS the whole time. Hope you don't mind if i update that.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on [stitch](https://github.com/sstephenson/stitch), [hem](https://github.com/spine/hem) (which is inspired by stitch, but has more neat features)  and [browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify).

Personally, I prefer hem. You can do something like this with it:

```
# app/lib/model.coffee

module.exports = class Model
  ...
```

.

```
# app/lib/util.coffee

helper1 = -> ...

helper2 = -> ...

module.export = {helper1, helper2}
```

.

```
# app/index.coffee

Model = require 'lib/model'
{helper1} = require 'lib/util'

# do whatever you want with required stuff
...
```

Hem takes care of compiling CoffeeScript on the fly and bundling all the needed code together (it also supports npm modules and arbitrary js libs as external dependencies for your code, see the docs for more details).

Comment: LOL, our answers differ in like only 10 seconds xD. I like that you provided more alternatives than just Browserify. I haven't had the best experience with Stitch (i tried long time ago though, so maybe it has improved).

Comment: =)
stitch is almost abandoned, as i remember, but i think of hem as its successor with more features and some extra neatness

Comment: Thanks for the useful info. Maybe i'll check out hem in the future. +1 :)